# How to add Data Connection for Oracle 11g in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, oracle11g, data-connections

I have Oracle 11g database which I need to connect in Visual studio 2015 (Enterprise Update 3).

I have install Oracle client 11 on my machine reference to following directories

I believe there are both Oracle Client 32-bit and 64-bit but not sure

[image]

When I try to add connection using .NET Framework Data Provider for OLEDB or .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle , I get following error

[image]

On my C:\Window\System32 I have found odbcad32; reference to following screen shot;

[image]

I am not what I am missing from picture. need help

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall both Oracle Client 32-bit and 64-bit in following location and it worked;

```
C:\app\KZ\product\11.2.0\client_32

C:\app\KZ\product\11.2.0\client_64
```

### To check which version of Client Instance is running on local machine

A simple way to find this out in Windows is to run SQLPlus from your Oracle homes's bin directory and then check Task Manager. If it is a 32-bit version of SQLPlus, you'll see a process on the Processes tab that looks like this:

```
 sqlplus.exe *32
```

If it is 64-bit, the process will look like this:

```
 sqlplus.exe
```